# Facing issue with divLogoBlock in the below code

Tags: html, css

I was facing problem with the below code. The divLogoBlock is not visible when i copied the entire page and pasted it in outlook as a signature. I think i have done something wrong with css. Help me

```
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>_-_</title>
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic,300italic,300,100italic,100" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<style>

    body                { font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;  color: #545555; margin: 0px; padding: 40px 0px 0px 3px; width:350px; position: absolute; }
    ul                  { float: left; margin: 33px -32px; }
    ul a                { margin-right: 6px; }
    ul a:last-child     { margin-right: 0;}
    .divLogoBlock       { height: 80px; width: 350px; background: #F3F3F3; }
    .logoBox            { padding:0px 0px; width: 350px; height: 4px; position: absolute; }
    .clear              { clear: both; }

</style>

</head>

<body>
    <h4 style="color:#545555; width:350px; margin: 0px">-----</h4>
    <h5 style="color:#545555; font-size:14px;font-weight:600; margin:20px 0 0 0; line-height:1; width:350px; margin-right:0px; ">Esesve Digumarthi</h5>
    <span style="font-size:14px;font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-weight:normal;">CEO</span>
    <p style="font-size:14px; margin-top:5px;color:#545555; width:350px">+91 9959 800 400  |  <a href="mailto:esesve@enhcorp.com" style="color:#252629; text-decoration:none; width:350px">esesve@enhcorp.com</a></p>

    <div class="divLogoBlock" style="overflow: auto;">
        <div class="logoBox" >
            <a style="float:left;" href="http://enhcorp.com/" target="_blank"><img style="margin:11px 0;" src="enh.jpg"></a>
            <ul>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/EnHcorp " target="_blank"><img src="facebook.png"></a>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/EnHcorp" target="_blank"><img src="twitter.png"></a>
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/enh-corp" target="_blank"><img src="linkedin.png"></a>
                <a href="https://plus.google.com/106470734549809877531/about" target="_blank"><img src="g_plus.png"></a>
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0Pdj548Y4A1NzAlX7-9GGw" target="_blank"><img src="youtube.png"></a>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="logoBox"><img src="bottomBar.jpg" width="350" height="4" align="top"></div>







</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the absolute url for the images, for starters. Right now, you've got them relatively linked.

Secondly, I would inline your css. You can technically leave the style tags in the header as well, but either do both, or just use inline-css. Email standards are archaic and a lot of clients will strip out anything but inline-css.

If you don't want to inline the css by hand, [MailChimp's inliner tool](http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/) works fairly well.